# Nexus I9250 - Got stuck with updating android 4.3 update

Tags: updates

Am not able to update my nexus i9250 to android 4.3. I have never rooted or tampered with the system earlier. Any system updates, i generally get a notification and then it starts getting updated. But now, under settings>about phone>system update, it states that "waiting to download - 139 mb" and is stuck there. There is no other icon for 'checking status updates' or 'download'.

Please let me know how to proceed in downloading the system update to 4.3?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your phone?

Comment: Are you on Wifi? Some Nexus versions default to only installing updates while on Wifi, but I can't remember where to check or disable this.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Onik's comment, make sure that `Wi-Fi only` is not checked. In the Samsung Galaxy S4, this can be found in: `System settings > More > About device > Software update > Wi-Fi only`. So, check the `About device` section of your phone.